# Class name to find nested tagname and assign value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyclassname

I have the following markup which I **can't modify**:

```
<li class="campID">
    <label for="input_2_14">Name</label>
    <div>
        <input name="input_14" id="input_2_14" type="text" value="" class="medium" tabindex="11">
     </div>
</li>
```

I want to select the input and change its value using vanilla JS (assume jQuery is not available).

I **can't** use the input name or ID as these are dynamic and will change.

I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
(function(){
  var listElement = document.getElementsByClassName('campID');
  var myInput = listElement.getElementsByTagName('input');
  myInput[0].value = 'John';
})();
```

Comment: you forgot to add `.` in between...should be like `listElement[0].getElementsByTagName('input');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are targeting IE8 and above then:

```
document.querySelector("li.campID input").value="John";
```

else:

Assuming for the first LI and Input alone:

```
var liListItem = document.getElementsByClassName("campID")[0],
    inputElement = liListItem.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
    inputElement.value = "John";
```

`document.getElementsByClassName("campID")` returns you NodeList. So you need to probably loop over and do.

Answer (score 0):

**`querySelector()`** and **`querySelectorAll()`** complete CSS selector.

> **querySelector()** returns only **first** matching **Element node** within Nodes.
>
> Whereas
>
> **querySelectorAll()** returns a **list of Node** containing **all matching Element** nodes within the Nodes.

You have to use **querySelectorAll()** selector for select multiple purpose,

```
var in =  document.querySelectorAll(".campID input");
in.value = 'John';
console.log(in);
```

**Console return:**

```
[input#input_2_14.medium, value: "John", item: function]
```

Answer (score -1):

I know it's been long time. Just thought of posting the solution that worked for me. For the below HTML

```
`
    <li class="list-summary-item">
        <span>Registration number</span>
        <span class="reg-mark">LT08 YJA</span>
    </li>
    <li class="list-summary-item">
        <span>Colour</span>
        <span><strong>BLACK</strong></span>
    </li>
    <li class="list-summary-item">
        <span>Make</span>
        <span><strong>VAUXHALL</strong></span>
    </li>
`

 <br>
document.getElementsByClassName('list-summary-item')[2].getElementsByTagName('span')[1].getElementsByTagName('strong')[0].innerHTML <br>
```

gives VAUXHALL.